# Understanding example of ECDSA P256

Tags: elliptic-curves, signature, sha-256, dsa, hash-signature

I am new to cryptography, I found the below Example on a nice website, but I am not able to understand the most of the terms used (H:Hash, K:Random number,E=?, Kinv=?,Rx=?=RY?,R=Private key?,D?,S? same in verification). Please help me with the Nomenclature/representation/what is what, of the example ill try to figure out other parts myself. Thanks ahead

```
##############################################################
Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm
Curve: P-256 Hash Algorithm: SHA-256
Message to be signed: "Example of ECDSA with P-256"
##############################################################
Signature Generation
H:       A41A41A12A799548211C410C65D8133AFDE34D28BDD542E4B680CF2899C8A8C4
E:       A41A41A12A799548211C410C65D8133AFDE34D28BDD542E4B680CF2899C8A8C4
K:       7A1A7E52797FC8CAAA435D2A4DACE39158504BF204FBE19F14DBB427FAEE50AE
Kinv:    62159E5BA9E712FB098CCE8FE20F1BED8346554E98EF3C7C1FC3332BA67D87EF
R_x:     2B42F576D07F4165FF65D1F3B1500F81E44C316F1F0B3EF57325B69ACA46104F
R_y:     3CE76603264661EA2F602DF7B4510BBC9ED939233C553EA5F42FB3F1338174B5
R:       2B42F576D07F4165FF65D1F3B1500F81E44C316F1F0B3EF57325B69ACA46104F
D:       C477F9F65C22CCE20657FAA5B2D1D8122336F851A508A1ED04E479C34985BF96
S:       DC42C2122D6392CD3E3A993A89502A8198C1886FE69D262C4B329BDB6B63FAF1
Signature
R:       2B42F576D07F4165FF65D1F3B1500F81E44C316F1F0B3EF57325B69ACA46104F
S:       DC42C2122D6392CD3E3A993A89502A8198C1886FE69D262C4B329BDB6B63FAF1
=============================================================
Signature Verification
Q_x:     B7E08AFDFE94BAD3F1DC8C734798BA1C62B3A0AD1E9EA2A38201CD0889BC7A19
Q_y:     3603F747959DBF7A4BB226E41928729063ADC7AE43529E61B563BBC606CC5E09
H:       A41A41A12A799548211C410C65D8133AFDE34D28BDD542E4B680CF2899C8A8C4
E:       A41A41A12A799548211C410C65D8133AFDE34D28BDD542E4B680CF2899C8A8C4
Sinv:    F63AFA3939902A4CA9F019CE77E5A59FB48E4CAA50EB9601EF02809E033F9057
U:       B807BF3281DD13849958F444FD9AEA808D074C2C48EE8382F6C47A435389A17E
V:       1777F73443A4D68C23D1FC4CB5F8B7F2554578EE87F04C253DF44EFD181C184C
Rprime.X:2B42F576D07F4165FF65D1F3B1500F81E44C316F1F0B3EF57325B69ACA46104F
Rprime.Y:3CE76603264661EA2F602DF7B4510BBC9ED939233C553EA5F42FB3F1338174B5
Rprime:  2B42F576D07F4165FF65D1F3B1500F81E44C316F1F0B3EF57325B69ACA46104F
Verification Passed!
```

Comment: @fgrieu Thank you so much

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ECDSA is specified in [SEC1](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#page=49). It's instantiation with curve P-256 is specified  in [FIPS 186-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=111) (or equivalently in [SEC2](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf) under the name `secp256r1`), and tells that it must use the SHA-256 hash defined by [FIPS 180-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.180-4.pdf#page=20).

I'll leave aside [ASN.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) decoration (since the question uses none), conversions between integer to bytestring of fixed width (which all are per big-endian convention), and to hexadecimal¹.

Signing using ECDSA on P-256 takes as input

- a private key $d$ (the question's `D`), which is a 32-byte bytestring
- a message, which is bytestring $M$ of $0$ to $2^{61}-1$ bytes
- a random number generator

and outputs

- a signature $S=(r,s)$ consisting of

  - an $r$ component (the question's `R`), which is a 32-byte bytestring
  - an $s$ component (the question's `S`), which is a 32-byte bytestring

Verifying a signature using ECDSA on P-256 takes as input

- a *trusted* public key $Q$, which should be a point of curve P-256 other than the point at infinity. It was originally computed as $d\,G$ during key generation. It is defined by its Cartesian coordinates

  - $x_Q$ (the question's `Qx`), which is a 32-byte bytestring
  - $y_Q$ (the question's `Qy`), which in the question is³ a 32-byte bytestring
- a message $M$
- the signature $S=(r,s)$ in the form output by the signature process.

and outputs *valid* (if the message matches the one signed and there was no errors) or *invalid* (in all other cases except a successful forgery).

---

The question's message is the 27-character `Example of ECDSA with P-256` converted to bytestring per some unspecified convention, likely ASCII or UTF-8. Both yield the same 27-byte bytestring $M$
`4578616D706C65206F66204543445341207769746820502D323536`

Both signing and verification manipulate $M$ only to compute it's SHA-256 hash $H$ (the question's `H`), which is a 32-byte bytestring. It is converted to an integer $e$ (the question's `E`), which when using P-256 thus SHA-256 is² $H$.

Signing is per [SEC1 section 4.1.3](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#page=50). In a nutshell:

- Draw a secret random number $k$ (the question's `K`) in range $[1,n)$, where $n$ is the order of the curve P-256. It is critically important that $k$ is uniformly distributed on this interval and independent⁴ of other $k$.
- Compute the Elliptic Curve point $R=k\,G$ of the curve P-256, where $G$ is the generator point. $R$ has Cartesian coordinates $(x_R,y_R)$ (the question's `R_x` and `R_y`), but only $x_R$ is needed.
- Compute  $r=x_R\bmod n$ (the question's `R`). If $r=0$ something went wrong⁵<sup>,</sup> ⁶.
- Compute $k^{-1}$ modulo $n$ (the question's `Kinv`), that is the integer in range $[1,n)$ with $k\,k^{-1}-1$ a multiple of $n$.
- Compute $s=k^{-1}(e+r\,d)\bmod n$. If $s=0$, something went wrong⁵.
- Output $(r,s)$.

CAUTION: Signing can be the target of various attacks, e.g. timing or other side channel, and fault injection. Mitigation of these attacks is difficult.

Verification is per [SEC1 section 4.1.4](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#page=52). In a nutshell:

- Check that the point $Q$ of coordinates $(x_Q,y_Q)$ is an ordinary point of P-256; otherwise, output *invalid*.
- Check  that $r$ and $s$ both are in range $[1,n)$; otherwise, output *invalid*
- Compute $s^{-1}$ modulo $n$ (the question's `Sinv`), that is the integer in range $[1,n)$ with $s\,s^{-1}-1$ a multiple of $n$.
- Compute $u_1=e\,s^{-1}\bmod n$ (the question's `U`)
- Compute $u_2=r\,s^{-1}\bmod n$ (the question's `V`)
- Compute the Elliptic Curve point $R=u_1\,G+u_2\,Q$ of the curve P-256, where $G$ is the generator point, and $Q$ is as determined by the public key. $R$ has Cartesian coordinates $(x_R,y_R)$ (the question's `Rprime.X` and `Rprime.Y`), but only $x_R$ is needed.
- If $R$ is the point at infinity, output *invalid*.
- If $e\bmod n\ne x_R\bmod n$, output *invalid* (see note⁶).
- Output *valid*.

DISCLAIMER: This contains simplifications and likely errors⁷. It is only meant as an aid to understand the standards.

---

¹ Hexadecimal is only for display purposes in the question and this answer. It's use in application is uncommon, and would waste space.

² Some implementations avoid the rare case $e\ge n$ (where $n$ is the order of the curve P-256) by reducing $H$ modulo $n$ to produce $e$. That changes the outcome of neither signature nor verification, thus does not hamper interoperability.

³ If point compression is used, $y_Q$ is reduced to its low-order bit, which combined with $x_Q$ and the curve's equation is enough to fully define point $Q$.

⁴ In particular, independence precludes reuse. If we want to be standards-conformant, that's including when signing the same message with the same key. However, from a security perspective it is safe, exclusively in this case, to reuse an earlier $k$. In some ECDSA variants, that's used to generate $k$ as the output of a Pseudo Random Function keyed by $d$ with input $H$.

⁵ It is then advisable to consider this an attack and erase/zeroize/burninate the private key, although the official thing to do is to try another $k$.

⁶ In overwhelmingly most cases occurring absent attack or deliberate test, $x_R<n$. The official thing is to handle the contrary unmoved, but it is a corner case worth consideration, if only to handle it as above⁵ during signature. The case $e\ge n$ is rare² (like one in four billion), but comparatively very common.

⁷ Thanks to [dave_thompson_085](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/12642/dave-thompson-085) for pointing some of the many errors I made, as usual; and pardon the endless stream of edits.

Comment: In your first (above the line) description, verification does NOT use d. Also 'avhoc' is not a word; 'awry' is but has the connotation 'wrong in only a minor unimportant way', so it would be better to use the simple, clear 'wrong'. OTOH I notice you spelled 'renowned' correctly, but left out 'of'; it used to be a purported 'rule' on Usenet that any post about grammatical correction would itself contain a grammatical error.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: thank you for the corrections. Having the private key in verification was baad!